# Kendo editor need to display image from dataabse/local folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert and display image using Kendo with MVC. I got the image and image is saving in Local folder.
But when I am trying to display it is not displaying in Editor.

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(Model => Model.URLAttachment)
           .Name("editor1")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;height:300px" })
            .Tools(tools => tools
            .Clear()
            .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
            .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
            .InsertUnorderedList().InsertOrderedList()
            .Outdent().Indent()
            .CreateLink().Unlink()
            .InsertImage()
            .InsertFile()
            .SubScript()
            .SuperScript()
            .TableEditing()
            .ViewHtml()
            .Formatting()
            .CleanFormatting()
            .FontName()
            .FontSize()
            .FontColor().BackColor()
            .Print()
            .ExportAs()
            )
```

Comment: What type is `URLAttachment`, and what type of html element is your `Html.Kendo().EditorFor()` generating?

Comment: My URLattachment is string type ' public string URLAttachment { get; set; }' But if we insert image from html editor  then I want to save and dissplay. [https://i.imgur.com/8CQKODa.png]

Comment: does the image actually come up in the image browser at all? If not then have you configured the default location for the imageURL at all? check this demo out it should help you https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/imagebrowser

Comment: No image is not dispying in editor

Comment: I want to get image from editor and save to local folder and display the same image on view